# I don't know how to create this asp.net web page layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I got an internship that uses ASP.NET but I've never used it, I only have experience with React. I'm having trouble with recreating the layout below does anyone have any ideas on how to do it?

So I have a layout with a master file that houses the "NAV", and it has multiple links to different page contents like "page1", "page2", "page3". When you press one of the page links the page will populate on the right side and have specific data pertaining to the page on the right side. So the data on the left is dependent on what populates on the right.

They want 2 content holders in the master file. One is leftside and the other is right side. How do I go about this? I keep thinking in React. Like I think I would get the data from the parent and pass it down to the right and left sides. But apparently that's not how asp.net works. Anyone have ideas?

[image: page layout]

Comment: "So the data on the left is dependent on what populates on the right." Do you mean when you click "page1", the right show "page1". Then click "page2", the right show "page2", and the left show  "page1" ?

Comment: are you using asp net framework or core ? and for the layout i assume you'd use bootstrap as will be easiest